# Date / Time condition in powershell - SharePoint - LastItemModifiedDate - LastRunTime

Tags: date, datetime, powershell, sharepoint

I'm making a script that collect two dates from the system. One from when the scheduling task has last run and the date a list has last been modified. Problem is that the datetime format isn't correct .

1. LastItemModifiedDate from a SPList - output format 04/09/2015 12:48:48
2. LastRunTime from a scheduling task - output format 09.04.2015 10:50:03

What I want to do is to check if the list has been changed since the last time the scheduling task has run.

```
$scheduledTask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SharePoint scheduling" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
$scheduledTaskLastRunTime = $scheduledTask.LastRunTime

$listExist = $spSourceWeb.Lists | where{$_.Title -eq $listName}
    if($listExist)
    {
        $spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$listName]

        if ($scheduledTaskLastRunTime -le $spSourceList.LastItemModifiedDate)
        {
            Write-Host " Changes found" -ForegroundColor Green
            SetListColumnToCopy($listName)
        }
```

Do I do the IF correct ?  What magic do I have to do to check the datetime?
I've read that "don't need a special format to compare dates in Powershell" but is it true in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ParseExact` static method from DateTime class.

```
$dateToCompare = [datetime]::ParseExact("09.04.2015 10:50:03","MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss", $null)
```